# How to Append key: value pairs to existing Mongodb objects using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');

const router = express.Router();

//User/Post model
const User = require('../models/DBmusevista');

//Welcome/register page
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('register'));

//Login page
router.get('/login', (req, res) => res.render('login'));

//Home page
router.get('/home', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('home', {user_mv: req.user}));

//Create topic page
router.get('/create-topic', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('create-topic', {user_mv: req.user}));


//Register handle
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const {firstname, lastname, username, email, password} = req.body;
    let errors =[];

    if(!firstname || !lastname || !username || !email || !password) {
        errors.push({msg: 'Please check all fields.'});
    };
    //Check password length
    if(password.length < 6) {
        errors.push({msg: 'Password should be at least 6 characters.'});
    };
    if(errors.length > 0){
        res.render('register', {  
            errors,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            username,
            email,
            password
        });
    }else {
        //Validation passed
        User.findOne({email: email})
        .then(user => {
            if(user){
                //User exists
                errors.push({msg: 'Email is already registered.'})
                res.render('register', {
                    errors,
                    firstname,
                    lastname,
                    username,
                    email,
                    password
                });
            } else {
                const newUser = new User({ //Check User
                    firstname,
                    lastname,
                    username,
                    email,
                    password
                });
                //Hash password
                bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => 
                bcrypt.hash(newUser.password,salt, (err, hash) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    //Set password to hash
                    newUser.password = hash;
                    //Save user
                    newUser.save()
                    .then(user => {
                        req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now registered and can now log in');
                        res.redirect('/login');
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
                }))

            }
        });
        
    }
});



//Post handle
router.post('/create-topic', (req, res) => {
let newObj = {
    title: req.body.title,
    category: req.body.category,
    vista: req.body.vista,
    description: req.body.description
}
User.updateOne({username: user_mv.username}, { $set: {post: newObj}});
res.send('Hello');
//This is the code that does not work. Anything else I've tried has not worked.
});



//Login handle
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const DBmusevistaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const DBmusevista = mongoose.model('DBmusevista', DBmusevistaSchema);

module.exports = DBmusevista;
```

When an individual comes to my website the beginning page ('/') is a registration for for my site. I have a post request for my MongoDB collection that creates a 'user register' object (fname, lname, username, email, pass). Once logged in ('/home') a user can then create a new post(s) form that is located in my create-topic.ejs file('/create-topic'). I'm new to using MongoDB so my question is how can I append the post submitted (title, category, vista, description) to an array for the users' object.

I'm not sure if I should add an array (posts: []) to DBmusevistaSchema and create a Post.Schema({key: value}) in my DBmusevista file? I tried using User.findOne but I cannot get it to work. Please help.

Comment: Do you want posts to be a different collection, So that an user can have 100s or 1000s of posts & you don't want to store all post info in user collection rather just postIds in user collection & when ever you want posts data you would query it from posts collection ? Or if posts are very less in number you can directly store entire posts information as a field (an array or single object) directly in user collection !! So what do you wanted to do ?

Comment: I'm familiar with mysql database and making relational tables. I didn't think MongoDB was like that. I assumed Mongo was not a relational DB. My intention was to make a 'post array' and store 100s or 1000s of post within that array. I'm guessing thats a bad idea?

How should I do it? How can I query users and posts to get the result I'm wanting?

Comment: There is no relation between collections unless you let you query know that there is a relation between two collections, by just querying user collection with userID you can get documents from posts collections based on a key(userID) stored in posts documents (But all data inserts into users or posts collections are completely independent ) !! It's up-to you how you wanted to store data into users, I would not suggest to store 1000s of posts objects in an array of user document, which would make user document bulky, as user collection is crucial(main landing page data) keep it simple..

Comment: It all depends on how you wanted to access data on your portal, 1) maybe you can have a reference of user document (an userID) for each post document & quickly get all posts for an user, 2) rather than storing entire (1000s of)posts object in an array (OR also) storing 1000s of posts document keys(posts ids) in an array as well..think thru your data needs & design well :-)

Comment: So maybe the solution is: creating a Post collection, and then create a hidden input field for my form and pass the users' _id for the value?

Comment: Yeah maybe it all depends on data needs how often posts are pulled from DB & which page and also based on which key they're being retrieved, here is a quick reference (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/), (Read data models examples & patterns page over there).. check on your UI/ database transactions & update this question with a design question to code :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  const pirs = await Pir.find();
  pirs.forEach(async (pir) => {
  let pir2 = new Pir();
  pir.isSubmitted = false;
  pir2 = pir;
  const out = await pir2.save();
  console.log(out);      
  });
} catch (err) {
  next(err);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].